# opencvのフォルダを移動するだけでインストールした場合と同じように利用できますか？

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi

Raspberry Pi 3 Model BでOpenCV2.4.9を用いたシステムを作りたいのですが, LXterminalの操作からインストールせずに, 別のRaspberry Piに既にインストールされているOpenCVのフォルダをコピーして移動するだけでも同様に利用できますか？

Answer (score 1):

`pip install` の実行時に環境によって設定を変更している場合があるので、コピーして使うことはあまり勧められません。

基本的には、requirements.txtに必要なパッケージを記録しておくのがベターです。もし、それをしていない場合は、以下のコマンドで`requirements.txt`を作成することができます。

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

そして、requirements.txtを使ってパッケージの一括インストールが可能です。

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Wheelになっていないパッケージがある場合で、インストールしたいマシンにはコンパイル環境を作成したくない場合は、同種のOSの別マシンでWheel版を作成することができます。その場合は、パッケージのソースで、setup.pyがあるフォルダーで以下を実行します。

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```